# XCTest send multiple key combination

Tags: ios, swift, xctest, ios-ui-automation, xctestcase

Does someone have an example of how to send multiple key combination when using XCTest / Swift? i.e. How would we send Shift + Command + H to the simulator when running a test?

I see the perform method exists:

```
perform(withKeyModifiers:block:)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielement/1500563-perform

But not sure how to use it.

Comment: What did you find @reutsey?
Did you come by a solution for this?

Comment: no unfortunately i didn't